# passing list of structs vs list of class as a parameter

Tags: c#

I am having a few methods that either return or needs the list of objects as below

```
public struct TankReading
{
    private readonly DateTime _readingTime;
    private readonly double _quantity;

    public TankReading(DateTime readingTime, double quantity)
    {
        _readingTime = readingTime;
        _quantity = quantity;
    }

    public DateTime ReadingTime => _readingTime;
    public double Quantity => _quantity;

    public TankReading AddReading(DateTime readingTime, double quantity)
    {
        return new TankReading(readingTime, this._quantity - quantity);
    }
}
```

as I want immutable objects, I have created a struct and creating a list of objects. The list can be of 200 objects. This 200 objects can be passed as a parameter to methods. Is it ok to pass a list of struct objects as parameters considering performance??

Comment: The list will be a reference type, so when you pass it there won't be any copying.

Comment: The `List` is a reference type, so when you pass or return the `List` you are passing or returning a reference to the `List` and not copying the `List` or the objects in it. However, accessing items from the `List`, such as with the indexer or in a `foreach` loop will cause them to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sean mentioned in the comments the `List<TankReading>` parameter will be a simple reference in both cases.

The real difference is that since `List<T>` stores the elements in an array, it will contain a lot of references if `TankReading` is a class, or no references at all (apart from the underlying array itself), if it is a struct. Obviously, using class elements means a larger impact on the GC.

Accessing an element in the list will copy the whole value though, but it still can be faster than reference type elements, especially if you then always read both properties in the end (accessing struct members from a local variable is faster than accessing reference type members because latter always requires a dereferencing).

And if you often pass a `TankReading` struct to other methods, you can consider to pass it as a `ref` parameter (or as `in`, but then make sure to make it a `readonly struct` to prevent the JITter emitting [defensive copies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/)).

But actually if performance is not a critical issue just go for the most logical and cleanest solution. And if `TankReading` has value semantics (and it seems so), then it's nothing wrong with defining it as a struct.